# How to switch to other user of same uid?

Tags: su

I created 2 users with the same uid/gid.

> test:x:1000:1000::/home/test:/bin/sh
>   test1:x:1000:1000::/home/test1:/bin/sh

When I do `su test1` and then `whoami` I get

```
test
```

How can I switch to user `test1` instead?

Comment: Which OS specifically?  Ubuntu?  BSD?  CentOS?

Comment: the specific OS is debian. Basically I tried this in the percona docker image.

Comment: You didn't create two users, you created a synonym for the same user. Without analysing it in detail, I guess the system uses the numeric IDs, so `whoami` searches `/etc/passwd` and returns the first matching entry. You can verify this by changing the order of the entries.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but how can I use the synonym. I don't want to change the /etc/passwd file for the ability to use test1.

Comment: Why two users with the same unique identifier?

Comment: The idea is to allow users to connect via ssh to a db server and then just login via the auth_socket.so plugin of mysql with their unix user name.  
Some users have more than 16 chars though. So to circumvent this, truncated unix usernames with an attached id with the same uid/gid are created in addition to the original usernames. The db user then is created like this:

   mysql> CREATE USER 'userwith15chars0'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;